# How can I calculate difference between max and min over varying time series lengths in R?

Tags: r, time-series, difference

I have a timeseries of water depth measurements (15-min intervals) and I want to calculate the tidal height of each tidal cycle. Tidal height is the absolute difference between max depth and min depth for an outgoing tide (or vice versa for an incoming tide, hence the absolute difference). To complicate things, not all of my sites have 6-hour variations between high and low tides; some have more, some have less. I would like to have a way of calculating the absolute difference between max and min values that vary in the length of time between consecutive highs and lows.

Just some random data:

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),20,2,
                         dimnames=list(c(), c("Time", "Depth"))),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
dat[,1] <- seq(from = 1, to = 20, by = 1)
dat[1:5,2] <- seq(from = 0.5, to = 2.5, by = 0.5)
dat[6:13,2] <- seq(from = 2.6, to = 0.4, by = -0.28)
dat[14:20,2] <- seq(from = 0.4, to = 2.8, by = 0.4)
```

The output should have the following results:

```
    Tide TidalHeight
1   1    2.1
2   2    2.2
3   3    2.4
```

Tide 1 would be the absolute difference between the low of 0.5 and high of 2.6, tide 2 would be the absolute difference between the high of 2.6 and low of 0.4, and tide 3 would be the absolute difference between the low of 0.4 and high of 2.8. The length of time between consecutive high and low tides varies, in the above example by 6, 8, and 6-time steps but in the real data this could be any number of time steps.

I would like to know how to automatically calculate the absolute difference between high and low tides that vary in length of time between tides.

Comment: How do you determine the length of time between consecutive high and low tides? Without that information, You can not solve your problem

Comment: This can be done, but the approach might be different depending on how "noisy" your data set is. Can we assume that when the tide is going out we never get a measurement fluctuation showing a transient increase in the tide, or a transient apparent dip when the tide is coming in?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes, you can assume that there are no transient increases/decreases on outgoing or incoming tides.

Comment: @Onyambu that is part of the question, since the spacing between highs and lows is not regular. I assume you could determine where the highs and lows are, then determine the time difference but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat$grp <- with(rle(sign(c(diff(dat$Depth),0))), rep(seq_along(values),lengths))
abs(diff(subset(dat, ave(grp,grp,FUN = seq_along)==1)$Depth))
[1] 2.1 2.2 2.4
```

Comment: I like this answer because you don't have to make the water depth monotonic assumption, rather the output is recored as NA.

Comment: Any particular reason for the edit (e.g. code runs faster)? I seem to get the same results either way. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If you assume that water depth is monotonic during both rising tides and falling tides, then @Onyamu's comment, whilst strictly correct, can be ignored.

The trick is to use `rle` to work out the number of observations for which each tide lasts.

```
library(tibble)

dat <- dat %>% 
         mutate(Direction=ifelse(Depth > lag(Depth), "Rising", "Falling"))
dat$Direction[1] <- dat$Direction[2]  # Handle the first observation.

tides <- rle(dat$Direction)
dat <- dat %>% 
         add_column(Tide=unlist(lapply(1:length(tides$length), function(x) rep(x, tides$length[x]))))
dat %>% 
  group_by(Tide) %>% 
  summarise(
    HighTide=max(Depth), 
    LowTide=min(Depth), 
    .groups="drop"
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    TideHeight=ifelse(
                 Tide == 1, 
                 HighTide - LowTide,
                 ifelse(
                   Tide == nrow(.), 
                   HighTide - lag(LowTide), 
                   lag(HighTide) - LowTide
                 )
               )
  )
dat
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   Tide HighTide LowTide TideHeight
  <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1     2.6      0.5        2.1
2     2     2.32     0.4        2.2
3     3     2.8      0.8        2.4
```

Comment: You have a small typo it should be `tides <- rle(dat$Direction)` not **ides**

Comment: @ChuckP: Thanks.  Fixed.  It's also been suggested that I should reverse the order of `"Falling"` and `"Rising"` in the first `mutate()`.  I think the original is correct but, in any case, the labels are arbitrary: all that's important is detecting the change points.  Even if the labels are inaccurate, they change at the required points. :)

Comment: Yes I had it the other way round for rising and falling but it doesn't matter. I got hung up on the steps after rle